# installed latest angular/cli(1.4.2) and start project with 'ng serve --prod'

Tags: angular-cli

Using 'ng serve' to start project has no issue.
The errors info like this.

```
95%emitting Unhandled rejection Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\\ng-webapp\node_modules\_@angular_animations@4.4.3@@angular\package.json'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:641:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:509:33)
    at LicenseExtractor.readPackageJson (C:\Users\\ng-webapp\node_modules\_license-webpack-plugin@1.0.1@license-webpack-plugin\dist\LicenseExtractor.js:121:23)
    at LicenseExtractor.parsePackage (C:\Users\\ng-webapp\node_modules\_license-webpack-plugin@1.0.1@license-webpack-plugin\dist\LicenseExtractor.js:21:32)
    at ModuleProcessor.processPackage (C:\Users\\ng-webapp\node_modules\_license-webpack-plugin@1.0.1@license-webpack-plugin\dist\ModuleProcessor.js:24:46)
    at ModuleProcessor.processFile (C:\Users\\ng-webapp\node_modules\_license-webpack-plugin@1.0.1@license-webpack-plugin\dist\ModuleProcessor.js:21:21)
    at moduleCallback (C:\Users\\ng-webapp\node_modules\_license-webpack-plugin@1.0.1@license-webpack-plugin\dist\LicenseWebpackPlugin.js:80:61)
    at SortableSet.forEach (native)
    at Chunk.forEachModule (C:\Users\\ng-webapp\node_modules\_webpack@3.5.6@webpack\lib\Chunk.js:159:17)
    ...
```

Comment: : no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ng-webapp\node_module

Comment: have you run npm install?

Comment: not 'npm install'  but 'cnpm install'.In China，some website can not be 
 accessed.

Comment: So you run it or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `npm install` before you run `ng serve --prod`. It seems to me that when AOT kicks in it can't find animation package.

Comment: He doesn't build He trying serve in production mode: check his Question again

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov sorry you are right. Will tune question but --prod means to turn off JIT and go with AOT

Comment: that's true ) "+1"

Comment: @Volodymyr Bilyachat  some website can not be accessed in here，some errors happened when using 'npm install'.it's not work .....

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat thank you ,it's running,the issue maybe from 'cnpm install',using 'npm install' and installing successful,using 'ng serve --prod' then it works.

Comment: @StevenZhu perfect you are welcome to mark as answered :)